# jQuery Datepicker has lower priority than other controls on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

[image]

If you look at the screenshot above, the calendar floats above the submit button. However, when I attempt to click any of the days in the top row, it registers the submit button as being pressed.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-content">
                <form method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm()" id="myForm" data-ajax="false">
                    <input type="text" name="transaction_date" class="date-input" data-inline="false" data-role="date" readonly="true">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain" align="center">
                        <input type="radio" name="transaction_type" id="radio-choice-1" value=0>
                        <label for="radio-choice-1">Expense</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="transaction_type" id="radio-choice-2" value=1>
                        <label for="radio-choice-2">Income</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I fix this so that anything I press on the calendar has priority?

Comment: [Can't replicate](http://jsfiddle.net/24KCx/)  Does your css have any z-index rules?

Comment: I used this wrapper that someone else wrote: https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper

Comment: I checked the css files, there weren't any z-index rules

Comment: @JTG Got it to replicate http://jsfiddle.net/24KCx/6/ jQuery mobile seems to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CSS of the jQuery mobile, the `ui-btn input, ui-btn button` has a `z-index:2` and the `ui-datepicker-div` has a `z-index:1` when it appears, which is causing your problem.

Adjusting with the z-index of the submit button fixed it for me.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24KCx/8/)

Alternatively, you could adjust the `ui-datepicker-div` z-index to be something a bit higher, but because its call is being abstracted away from you, you would have to rummage around the ui core to find out where the adjustment is being made.